# Toggle Element by click

Tags: javascript, html

You can see an example of my script.
When you click "Click me", will appear below "something" ...
But I want that when I click somewhere else "something" is no longer there.
I need a new JS, I am not good in javascript, I'm just going to learn it. I hope you have understand me.

PS: Sorry for my english

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Titel</title>

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function login() {

    document.getElementById('log2').style.display='inline-block';

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <li id="log" onclick="login()">Einloggen</li>
    </div>
    <ul id="log2" style="display: none;">somthing
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XAFZb/)

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/XAFZb/14/

Comment: I've posted an answer with my solution (with a little bit reformatted code).

Comment: Just as a comment: `<li>` should always be withing `<ul>` and `</ul>` and a `<ul>` can't have content without `<li>`. So your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

add the following script -

```
document.onclick = function(e){
    var e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

    if(target.id=="log")return;

    document.getElementById("log2").style.display = "none"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Uzf5H/)**

html

```
<div>
    <li id="log">Einloggen</li>
</div>
<ul id="log2" style="display: none;">somthing</ul>
```

javascript

```
function login() {
    document.getElementById('log2').style.display = 'inline-block';
}
window.onclick = function (e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    if (e.target == document.getElementById('log')) {

        document.getElementById('log2').style.display = 'inline-block';

    } else {
        console.log('window');
        document.getElementById('log2').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("log").onclick = login
function login(e) {
   document.getElementById('log2').style.display='inline-block';
   e.stopPropagation()
}

document.body.onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById("log2").style.display = "none";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XAFZb/20/

Answer (score 0):

I've rearranged your code to be more reusable and readable. (**Edit:** Clicking 'login' toggles $loginContent.)

```
var $loginLink = document.getElementById("log");
var $loginContent = document.getElementById("log2");

function showLoginBox(show) {
    if (show) {
        $loginContent.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        $loginContent.style.display = "none";
    }
}

$loginLink.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    showLoginBox(!opened);
    opened = !opened;
    evt.stopPropagation();
});

var opened = false;

window.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    if (evt.target == $loginContent) {
        return;
    }
    showLoginBox(false);
    opened = false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XAFZb/23/

Please also check your invalid HTML structure. In your original jsFiddle, you have a closing `</div>` without an opening one. Furhtermore, you can only place `<li>` elements inside `<ul>` or `<ol>` list tags.

Comment: hey, can you change your script that when i click a second time on Einlogggen that 'log2' is also closed

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML Just create a counter variable (`var counter = 0`) which counts the clicks. If it is >= 1, you should close 'log2'.

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML You should **really** learn HTML, JS, etc.! SO is actually not a code request platform, but I've done it for you - maybe because you're also coming from Germany :-)